# Criação de Trigger para INSERT em outra tabela no IBexpert

Tags: firebird, trigger

Bom dia, me surgiu a necessidade de criar um controle de estoque porém eu nunca havia utilizado trigger.

Eu tenho 3 tabelas `COMPRA` `ABASTECIMENTO` e `MOVIMENTO_ESTOQUE`

Tabela `MOVIMENTO_ESTOQUE` :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria que quando eu fizesse uma compra gravasse todos os dados exceto o `COD_ABASTECIMENTO` e no `TIPO` fosse gravado um `C` de crédito e quando eu fizer um abastecimento fosse gravado todos os dados menos `COD_COMPRA` e `COD_ITEMCOMPRA` e no `TIPO` fosse gravado um `D` de débito, como eu criaria essa trigger para controle do estoque ?

Comment: Eu logo respondo sua pergunta, mas já deixo de antemão um aviso: isso seria melhor se feito com uma view, pra que ela sempre visse o estado atual das duas tabelas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estou assumindo que o nome dos campos são iguais, e deixei vazio no código porque caso você use um contador, aí você pode chamar ele. Com isso você deve conseguir fazer para o abastecimento também.

```
CREATE TRIGGER bi_movcompra for COMPRA
  BEFORE INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO MOVIMENTO_ESTOQUE(CODIGO, DATA, COD_TANQUE, COD_PRODUTO, QUANTIDADE, TIPO, COD_COMPRA, COD_ITEMCOMPRA) VALUES(<COD>, NEW.DATA, NEW.COD_TANQUE, NEW.COD_PRODUTO, NEW.QUANTIDADE, 'C', NEW.COD_COMPRA, NEW.COD_ITEMCOMPRA)
END
```